# how to make jboss 7 resolution domain adress?

Tags: jboss, dns, call

I am deploying java/jee application on jboss as 7.1 and I will to call the application not with the default address like "http://domain.com:3306/index.xhml" but with the domain address directly "domain.com", how can i do it?

cordially